# Why fragment may load on the first time slowly but in an instant any following time

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i have some light fragments, some medium and bigger ones, I've noticed that some of the fragments (may depends on system resources) may take time  ranging 400ms to 1000ms on first load but anytime following the first load it opens in an instant.

I want to harness that beahviour, how can i force load the fragment before the user shoots FragmentTransaction? could be an hack to load all the fragments on splash screen behind some constraint but any other opinions?

Comment: You can try to add all the fragments to the manager and hiding/showing when needed. But that is not the recommended way of doing it, as then you'd be eating on the user's resources

Comment: @AhmadSattout That is not quite the way to do it i worry. And that may depend of project structure, in my case theres some main fragments and their sub ones and some general ones

Comment: The idea is that Fragment Manager can save some of the state of the Fragment, and skip to the UI when the Fragment is already ready. It's by design, so I'm not sure there's any other way to exploit it